# Virtualized real machine

Tags: virtualization, pxe

how do I virtualize a computer with Windows? Of the genre, when a real machine boots, it will boot through eg pxe, and look for an operating system to run, on a server.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a thin cilent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to turn a physical machine into a virtual machine? If so you need to specify which virtualization platform (aka hypervisor) you'd like to use so people can get you a relevant p2v (Physical to Virtual) 'convertor'. I assume based on your limited wording you may be new to this so likely the two big names: Microsoft Hyper-V OR VMWare.

**Microsoft Hyper-V OLD official convertor**: [Disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd)

[Apparently their 'Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter' (MVMC) has been retired](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd). Guessing they aren't invested in helping you convert a physical machine much, they want purchases of new licenses likely or simply suggest a fresh OS install on a VM then bring the SW/Data/Configuration over. [A guide on both tools](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/microsoft-virtual-machine-converter-hyper-v-p2v/), from a vendor possibly pushing one of their own tools. [A Spiceworks discussion](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2145906-best-free-product-to-perform-p2v-hyper-v) linking other guides/tools.

**VMware Official Converter**

- [vCenter Converter Standalone](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/downloads/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/6_2_0) ([link 2](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html)). It mentions standalone as their vCenter product is a paid product, but this limited tool is free. [Guide 1](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vCenter-Converter-Standalone/6.2/com.vmware.convsa.guide/GUID-D0C4114C-8A7C-42AE-AB72-A05E352CCCD2.html), [2](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005129), [3](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/vmware-converter-p2v-and-v2v-migration/)
- [Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player.html#compare) (their free hypervisor that installs on top of Windows/Linux) apparently can do some kind of conversion?

Comment: I think, that I did not explain myself well, I wanted, that when a real machine of the boot, it goes to fetch its operating system for pxe, and thus all the compotacional power is in the server, where in fact is the operating system, and that it was possible on other machines, to access that machine using for example the "Remote desktop" (I know this is possible, with linux, but I don't know if it is possible with windows)

Video showing this linux boot, using pxe (it is in portuguese, but you can activate subtitles) https://youtu.be/CmbkB893u78?t=333

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this information. PXE booting just loads the operating system from a server, the software still runs on the local PC CPU, memory, etc. VNC/RDP only bring the visual to the local PC, CPU, Memory power is from server. Others have pointed out thin clients which PXE boot basically RDP & the power again is on the server (since its running RDP)

Comment: Good example here....